# Holoviews AdjointLayout with Bokeh Widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

I am trying to append an AdjointLayout of a Scatter plot with two supporting histograms to a Bokeh dashboard. However, whenever trying to incorporate the two in a single row, the Bokeh widgets encounter display issues and the AdjointLayout never scales. Is this the current expected behavior or is here a different approach I need to take to currently accomplish this?

Minimal Example of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import Select
from bokeh.io import curdoc

renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh').instance(mode='server')

np.random.seed(10)
data = np.random.rand(100,4)

opts = {}
opts['color_index'] = 2
opts['size_index'] = 3
opts['scaling_factor'] = 50
points = hv.Points(data, vdims=['z', 'size']).opts(plot=opts)

fields = ['berry', 'cherry', 'dairy']
x = Select(title='X-Axis:', value=fields[0], options=fields)
y = Select(title='Y-Axis:', value=fields[1], options=fields)

dashboard = points + points[0.3:0.7, 0.3:0.7].hist()

app = renderer.get_plot(dashboard).state

dashboard = layout([
    [[x, y], app],
])

curdoc().add_root(dashboard)
```

Using Bokeh 0.13.0 and Holoviews 1.10.5

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is going wrong for you? When I try the code both the widgets and the plots render correctly, although they don't do anything since the widgets and plots are not linked in any way.

Comment: What is "AdjointLayout" ? It's not any class that's part of Bokeh

Comment: @bigreddot AdjointLayout is a class that is a part of Holoviews. The scatter chart with the histogram is the component that is an AdjointLayout

Comment: @philippjfr the example works as is? I can get it to render using scale_width='fixed' but I'm unable to get it to behave correctly using the 'scale_width' setting